# Pointer to something, can't understand what type

Tags: c++

What is this weird type?

```
 struct struct1 { struct1 * mptr; };
    typedef struct1 *  struct1 ::* ptrTo2;
```

I don't understand what the

```
typedef struct1 *  struct1 ::* ptrTo2;
```

is.

Comment: [Pointer to member.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr034.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ptrTo2` is a pointer to a member of type `struct1` which has type `struct1*`. It is basically the type you get when you do `&struct1::mptr`. To use one of these pointers, you need an object on which the member is accessed, e.g.

```
ptrTo2 memPtr = &struct1::mptr;
struct1 object;
object.*memPtr = 0;
```

Comment: Why couldn't this have been written like "typedef struct1::(struct1*) * ptrTo2 ??

Comment: This seems obfuscating: what kind of scenario would require this kind of construct?

Comment: @DavidKernin: I don't think you notation is any more logical than the one chosen the language already! Also, note that you can also create pointer to member functions, e.g., `int (struct1::*mem_fn)(double)` would be a pointer to a member function of `struct1` called `mem_fn` which takes one `double` argument and returns and `int`. I don't see how to make that work with your notation.

Comment: I don't know, that's the problem

Comment: @slashmais: Assume you have multiple `int` data members in your class `S` and you want to apply the same function to each one of them. Passing an `int S::*` to a corresponding function accessing the data members through a pointer to member avoids code duplication. If the function is templatized on the actual type, the various members can even be of different types. Although I wouldn't expect pointer-to-members be used frequently, there are occasional uses where they come in handy.